# How to return a string from pandas.DataFrame.info()

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to display the output from [`pandas.DataFrame.info()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.info.html) on a `tkinter` text widget so I need a string. However `pandas.DataFrame.info()` returns `NoneType` is there anyway I can change this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(10).reshape(5,2)
cols = 'a', 'b'
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
df_info = df.info()
print(df_info)
type(df_info)
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
info_str = ""
df_info = df.info(buf=info_str)
```

Is it possible to get `pandas` to return a string object from `DataFrame.info()`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In the documentation you linked, there's a `buf` argument:

> buf : writable buffer, defaults to sys.stdout

So one option would be to pass a StringIO instance:

```
>>> import io
>>> buf = io.StringIO()
>>> df.info(buf=buf)
>>> s = buf.getvalue()
>>> type(s)
<class 'str'>
>>> print(s)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 2 columns):
a    5 non-null float64
b    5 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 160.0 bytes
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I saw the `buf` argument and tried to give it an empty string to write to but it didn't work. Do you know where I could find a list of valid objects that can be passed to buf?